# How can I find out more about my classic ASP environment?

Tags: com, vbscript, asp-classic, sunone

I'm trying to make some modifications to some old ASP pages running VBScript on a server that I don't have a lot of information about. The people who would have that information are off in another department/hard to track down/probably wouldn't be able to provide complete information anyway.

I would like to run an ASP script that would get the server to tell me about itself. Information I would like to know is stuff like:

- the version number of the server
- version of Windows it is running on
- the version of VBScript am I using
- what dll's and COM objects are available for me to use

Bearing in mind that I know very little about ASP, what is some code that I could put into an ASP file I could run on the server so that it would provide me this information?

---

Based on the ServerVariables clue provided in the comment by JB King, below, I wrote this code and put it in an ASP:

```
<%   
    dim x
    for each x in Request.ServerVariables
      response.write("<p>" & x & ": " & Request.ServerVariables(x) &"</p>")
    next
%>
```

This provided a lot of the information I needed - such as telling me that I'm actually running under something called Chili!Soft on a Solaris server, not Windows, which probably explains why the stuff I want to use from the Microsoft library doesn't work.

I still would like a good way of figuring out what COM objects are available in this environment...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, you've found out that the server is running Chili!Soft.  You can probably assume that the COM objects will mostly be limited to the basics like the [ASP Built-in (intrinsic) objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524716.aspx),  and some form of data access like [ADO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms676795.aspx).  I don't know of an easy way to blindly list the registered COM classes for a server with VBScript.  My guess is that this wouldn't work so well on a Solaris platform anyways since COM registers classes in the Windows registry... does Solaris have a Windows registry? ;)

Here are some links to the official Chili!Soft reference pages (aka [Sun ONE ASP](http://docs.sun.com/source/817-2514-10/)):

[ASP Built-in Objects Reference](http://docs.sun.com/source/817-2514-10/Ch9_ASPBuiltIn.html)
- covers: Application, ASPError, Request, Response, Server & Session objects
[Sun ONE ASP Installed Components](http://docs.sun.com/source/817-2514-10/Ch8_BuildApp24.html) - Note that these may not be available on your installation since you might be on an older version of the platform (add-on components such as: Ad Rotator, Browser Capabilities, Counters, etc)

[Sun ONE ASP XML Control](http://docs.sun.com/source/817-2514-10/XMLSupport2.html) - Supposed to correspond to the COM interfaces in MSXML 1.0

Also, if the server has Chili!Beans installed and enabled you can access Java components in VBScript as if they were COM components.  More info on that [here](http://docs.sun.com/source/817-2514-10/Ch12_ChiliBean2.html).

Lastly, you may want to try and access the Administration Console for Sun ONE ASP via either http://[HOSTNAME]:5100 or http://[HOSTNAME]/caspsamp.  Detailed instructions for accessing the admin console can be found [here](http://docs.sun.com/source/817-2514-10/Ch2_AdminConsole2.html).  If you can manage to get in I am sure there is a lot more information to discover about the server in the admin console.

Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks. After mulling it over, I've decided against implementing any Chili!Soft specific code, on the assumption that it will break if this application ever gets moved to a different server as part of some future upgrade. So I've basically decided to make do with the least-common-denominator functions available to both Chili!Soft and to ASP on Windows. So, this means I'll be storing my data in flat files instead of structured XML. Not elegant, but I can live with it.

Answer (score 2):

[Server Variables](http://www.w3schools.com/asp/coll_servervariables.asp) would be a starting point though I'm not sure how well that would work as if you could remote onto the server that may be a better option.  You may also want to look into COM objects as those were used with ASP that involve some DLLs.

You may want to look into what version of IIS is being used and what ISAPI filters are on server for a couple of other points along with what logging is there on the server.